# Read Repeated node value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to covert XML to HTML using XSLT. In this area I need to read repeated node values.

Consider this scenario

```
<root>
  <test>
  <ID> 123 <</ID>
  <Name> MyName </Name>
  <Country> India </Country>
  <Books>
     <language> C </language>
     <language> C++ </language>
     <language> Java </language>
     <language> XML </language>
  </Books>
</root>
```

In this example am able to read all the node values like

```
   <xsl:value-of select="ID">
```

except "language" node.
I need output like C C++ Java XML .
Any idea????

Comment: you need xsl foreach, or xsl template to do this sort of thing. For each will probably do the job, based on the data you've posted.

Comment: Post your xslt code. Will correct it for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="Books/language">
 <xsl:value-of select "." />
 <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
string(/*/*/Books)
```

This XPath expression evaluates to the **[string value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value)** of the first (in your case there is just one) `Books` element that is a child of any element that is a child of the top element of the XML document.

By definition the **[string value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value)** of an element is the concatenation (in document order) of all of its text-node descendents.

**Complete code**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="string(/*/*/Books)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided (but corrected to be made well-formed!!!) XML document**:

```
<root>
    <test>
        <ID> 123 </ID>
        <Name> MyName </Name>
        <Country> India </Country>
        <Books>
            <language> C </language>
            <language> C++ </language>
            <language> Java </language>
            <language> XML </language>
        </Books>
    </test>
</root>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result is output**:

```
 C  C++  Java  XML
```

Comment: Hey Infant Programmer, You are back -- and you are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few pointers, but really, I strongly recommend that you spend a couple of hours working through a decent tutorial such as http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Firstly, as Dimitrie pointed out your XML is not well formed. I am a little surprised that your XSLT parser didn't get upset about this. Your have an opening Test tag that is never closed and an extra < in your closing Id tag. Also, your value-of expression isn't closed properly

Secondly, you say "In this example am able to read all the node values like..." This sort of doesn't make sense without seeing the rest of your code and I am guessing that it looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's critical to understand what the xsl:template match bit means if you are going to be able to write XSLT. XSLT works through your document piece by piece applying rules that you give it to turn the input document into the output document.

At each stage you need to know where it is looking in the document. This is known as the "context". In the code above, the rule is applied when it gets to /root. This means the thing in angle brackets called root that has no enclosing thing in angle brackets.

Given this context, the XSLT expressions are relative to it. It's a bit like DOS directory paths. Unless you know the current directory then relative file paths don't mean much.

So, in your example, select="ID" means the value of the ID tag that is the child of the current context i.e. /root/ID.

Your question was how to the language element. Well, if the engine's context is /root then you need to go down to books and then down again to language so the expression would be ID/books/language

Good on you for trying to learn XSLT though. It isn't really that hard and it's an extraordinarily powerful language for processing XML.